# Stringing across hollow shapes used for cutting

Tags: creality-ender-3, stringing

I am having this issue with stringing when printing these small clay cutters. The stringing is across any small cut out area. I have calibrated the temp, retraction distance, retraction speed, and E-Step. Maybe I need to calibrate flow as well for this issue?

Printer: Ender 3 S1 Pro

Filament: PLA

Settings:

Temp:195C

Retraction distance: 0.3mm

Retraction speed: 45mm/s

Retraction minimum travel: 0mm (so retraction can happen over the small areas)

[image: Here are my print results]

Is there anyway to optimize the path of the hot end? The stringing perfectly follows how the hot end jumps over the different cutter areas.

[image: Here is what my hot end travel looks like in Cura]

And just for reference, 0.3mm for retraction distance seemed low from what I've been reading online, but this is the retraction tower I ran and how I got that number:

[image: Here is my retraction tower]

Just today I got my filament in a dryer and it has been running all day, so the filament should be dry.

I'm willing to try any calibration again or literally anything! Thank you